# How to validate if cheerio doesn't find an element?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to validate if an element is not found

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const $ = cheerio.load(`<ul id="fruits">
  <li class="apple">Apple</li>
  <li class="orange">Orange</li>
  <li class="pear">Pear</li>
</ul>`)

console.log($('xyz'))
```

It returns a valid object.

How can I validate the object wasn't found?

Answer (score 4):

Using the `length` property does the trick

```
$('xyz').length
```

Prints 0